# Cthulu Filter Parser to Generate queries with GORM

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

This is a str8 forward question. I will be sending in filters in my requests in the form :

```
["EQ","my_field",1],["IN","myfield",1,2,3,4]
```

That much already works. But does anyone have a way to deal with more complex filters to say something like :

```
["IN","my_field",1,2,3,4] AND ["GTE","myfield2",4]
```

There has to be something that exists that will parse filters of this nature or at least a well thought out solution to the problem.

Comment: Just wondering, how's the second one more complex? Or is the `or` in the 1st one not a logical disjunction but a plain english conjunction?

Comment: ahh that could be more clear the "or" was just an english conjunction. i will fix it ty